# block matrix headings

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix, block, bordermatrix

I'm trying to write the following block matrix but i have some points i need a help to fix it. first, in the block matrix where i write some headings `(k_1, k_2 n-k_1-k_2)` there is between them vertical line i don't want to keep it. i need it only in the block matrix inside and for the diagonal matrix `\lambda_1 \ddots \lambda_1` and the others i don't want the space before the first row i.e. before the `\lambda_1` and `\lambda_2`.

Hope someone can help me. Here is the code that i write it:

```
\[
\begin{blockarray}{cc|c|c}
 & k_{1}&k_2&n-k_{1}-k_{2}\\ 
 \begin{block}{c(c|c|c)}
   &\lambda_1  &        &        \\  
 k_1  & \hspace{0.75cm} \ddots \hspace{0.75cm} & & \\  
   & \hspace{2cm} \lambda_1 &        &        \\\cline{2-4}
    &  &\lambda_2   &        \\  
   k_2 & \Phi &\hspace{0.75cm}  \ddots \hspace{0.75cm} & \\  
    &  &   \hspace{1.5cm}  \lambda_2     &        \\  \cline{2-4}
    &  &   &\\
 n-k_1-k_2   & \Phi & \Phi & \bar{\bar{M}}_3\\
    &   &    &\\
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. We have to use 10 columns and `booktabs` to have horizontal rules that do not get across the parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools, blkarray, booktabs}

\begin{document} 

\[ \aboverulesep = 0pt \belowrulesep = 0pt
\begin{blockarray}{r*{3}{>{\scriptstyle}c>{\scriptstyle}c@{\enspace}>{\scriptstyle\quad}c}}
    & & {k_{1}} & & & k_2& & & \mathclap{n-k_{1}-k_{2}} \\%
 \begin{block}{>{\scriptstyle}r(*{2}{ccc|}cc>{\enspace}c<{\enspace})}
   &\rule{0pt}{3ex}\:\lambda_1 & & & & & & & & \\
 k_1 & & \ddots & & & & & & & \\
   & & & \lambda_1 & & & & & & \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-10}
     & & & &\lambda_2 & & & & & \\
   k_2 & & \Phi & & & \ddots \hspace{0.75cm} & & & & \\
    & & & & & & \lambda_2 & \\
   \cmidrule(lr){2-10}
    & & & & & & & & & \\
 n-k_1-k_2 & & \Phi & & & \Phi & &\enspace &\overline{\overline{M}}_3 & \\[0.5ex]
 \end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `nicematrix` which has been designed to draw such matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle , code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|ccc|c}[first-row,first-col]
    &           & k_1    &           &           & k_2    & & n-k_1-k_2 \\
    & \lambda_1 &        &           &           &        & & \hspace*{2cm} \\
k_1 &           & \Ddots &           &           &        & \\
    &           &        & \lambda_1 &           &        & \\
\hline
    &           &        &           & \lambda_2 &        & \\
k_2 &           &  \Phi  &           &           & \Ddots &           &\\
    &           &        &           &           &        & \lambda_2 & \\
\hline 
    &           &        &           &           &        &  & \\

n-k_1-k_2 &     & \Phi    &          &           & \Phi   &            & \overline{\overline{M}}_3 \\
    &           &        &           &           &        &  & \\
\end{pNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the previous code]